# Converting a web.config rewrite rule to Apache format

Tags: apache, web-config

I would like to convert this web.config

```
<rule name="cambiarPass" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^cambiarPass/" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

to .htaccess. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that I do not use IIS but the provided code seems pretty self-explanatory in terms of how it should be converted to an Apache rewrite rule.

The `<match url="^cambiarPass/" />` line is set to apply URL rewriting only to URLs (paths) which begin with `cambiarPass/`. The

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php" appendQueryString="false" />
```

line is the one doing the rewriting and redirecting all matched URLs to  `modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php`. The `appendQueryString` attribute is obviously a synonym for the Apache [QSA rewrite flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) meaning the rewrite process will discard and ignore any existing query string data during the rewrite. The `stopProcessing` attribute seems to be yet another equivalent for the Apache [L rewrite flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) meaning if this rule is matched any additional rewrite rules that might follow the current rule will simply be ignored.

Here is the complete code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cambiarPass/ modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php [L]
```